# Using object-bound classes in scala

Tags: scala, dependent-type

I am trying to write code to wrap a modeling library.  A very simplified version of the model looks like this:

```
class Model() {
    class Thing(val name: String) {
        private[Model] val foo = name + " foo "

        def join(other: Thing) = new Thing(foo + other.foo)
    }

    def thing(name: String) = new Thing(name)
}
```

`foo` is actually some data structure that is tied to the specific instance of the `Model`.  Using a `Thing` from two different `Model`s does not make sense, and I think this syntax prevents that.

I have several scala tests call `model.thing` and use them, which works as desired.

I then started to write an abstraction layer on top of this:

```
class Widget(name: String)(implicit val model: Model) {
    val thing = model.thing(name)
}

class CompoundWidget(name: String, children: Seq[Widget])(implicit val model: Model) extends Widget(name)
{
    val combo =
        children.sliding(2).foreach(pair => pair(0).thing join pair(1).thing)
}
```

This fails to compile:

```
Simple.scala:20: error: type mismatch;
  found   : (some other)_1.type(in value $anonfun)#model.Thing where type (some other)_1.type(in value $anonfun) <: com.proteus.orchestration.mediatorModule.scheduling.Widget with Singleton
  required: _1.type(in value $anonfun)#model.Thing where type _1.type(in value $anonfun) <: com.proteus.orchestration.mediatorModule.scheduling.Widget with Singleton
         children.sliding(2).foreach(pair => pair(0).thing join pair(1).thing)
                                                                ^
```

This appears to be my attempt to prevent mixing models working too well.  The compiler does not know that the `Seq[Widget]` I am passing in uses the same `Model` for each element, so it is giving an error.

Is there a way around this?  The thing that seems likely to work (but I have not tried) is to make a class to hold the entire abstraction layer, so then the compiler can see that I am always using the same instance of `Model`.  However, that means that, regardless of how large it grows, I would need to keep all of the code in a single file, which will eventually become unwieldy.

My background is a Java programmer starting to use Scala, so I may just need to have the Scala Way (tm) explained to me.

Comment: It's a type problem. model.thing("") creates an object of model.Thing type, model2.thing("") creates an object of model2.Thing type. That works as you expect, the problem is that the same apply to Widget. I was doing some test and widget1.thing gives me an object of type widget1.model.Thing, and widget2.thing gives me an object of type widget2.model.Thing. With diff types there is no way to use join between them. You can fix that by changing Thing for Model#Thing, but that allow you to mix models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're playing with here are [dependent types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type). One way to do this is to make sure that both `Widget` and `CompoundWidget` refer to the same `Model` by putting it in a shared scope:

```
class View(val model: Model) {
  class Widget(name: String) {
    val thing = model.thing(name)
  }

  class CompoundWidget(name: String, children: Seq[Widget]) extends Widget(name) {
    val combo =
        children.sliding(2).foreach(pair => pair(0).thing join pair(1).thing)
  }
}
```

I call it `View` because I assume you're going for something like [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). I suppose the reason you're using implicits is to reduce boilerplate. You can achieve something similar here:

```
val view = new View(new Model)
import view._
new Widget("foo")  // No need to specify View or Model
```